# How to put Property in json data for google area chart

Tags: json, google-visualization

I want to Colorize certain areas in the area chart. Therefore I have the following PHP code to set up a JSON Document with data from a DB:

(The evaluation and setting of the color is still missing)

```
$rows = array();
$table = array();

$result = $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM Test ORDER BY DateTime');

$table['cols'] = array(


    array('label' => 'Date', 'type' => 'string'),
    array('label' => 'Value', 'type' => 'number'),
    array('label' => '', 'type' => 'string', 'p' => '{ "role": "style" }')    
);



foreach ($result as $r) 
    {

     $switch_array = array();



    $switch_array[] = array('v' => (string) $r['DateTime']);      

    $switch_array[] = array('v' => (int) $r['Value']); 

    $switch_array[] = array('v' => (string) "area { color: green }"); 




      $rows[] = array('c' => $switch_array);




    }

    $table['rows'] = $rows;

$jsonTable = json_encode($table);
```

When I try to print it via:

```
         var data2 = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?= $jsonTable2 ?>);
```

I got the error message:

*Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'role' in { "role": "style" }×*

I want to do the same like this with JSON Data:

```
data2.addColumn('string', 'Date');
            data2.addColumn('number', 'Value');
            data2.addColumn({type:'string',role:'style'}); // certainty col.
            data2.addRows([
                ['2014-12-01',100, 'area { color: green }'],
                ['2015-01-01',200, 'area { color: green }'],
                ['2015-02-01',300, 'area { color: green }'],
                ['2015-03-01',400, 'area { color: green }'],
                ['2015-04-01',500, 'area { color: red }']
            ]);
```

How do I get the *role:'style'* Property correct into JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `role` key should not be included as property within `'p'`,

```
array('label' => '', 'type' => 'string', 'p' => '{ "role": "style" }')
```

it should just be another key on the column...

```
array('label' => '', 'type' => 'string', 'role' => 'style')
```